# How to get child in this.state array

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting some userData from the securestore and try to put it into the this.state and then display the items in seperate text fields. So for example:

Firstname: Mark
Lastname: lol

When I display the this.state.UserData it prints all array data but i want to access only a child of it. How can i do this?

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        UserData: ''
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync('userData')
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ UserData: data })
    });

}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>
                {this.state.UserData['FirstName']}<-- not doing anything
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Secure store set function:

```
userLogin = () =>{
            const {Email, passWord} = this.state;
            if(Email !== "" && passWord !== ""){
                fetch('', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
                        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        action: 'login',
                        email: Email,
                        password: passWord
                    })
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => { 
                            //console.log(responseJson);
                            if(responseJson !== "" && responseJson !== '0'){
                                Alert.alert(
                                    'Succes',
                                    'ingelogd!',
                                    [
                                        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                                    ],
                                    { cancelable: false }
                                )
                                try {
                                    SecureStore.setItemAsync('userData', JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                                } catch (error) {
                                    alert('Er ging iets mis, probeer het later opnieuw ' . error);
                                }
                     }
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code where you store the userdata into SecureStore?

Comment: Also, it'll be helpful if you set the initial state of UserData to an object rather than a string

Comment: Ok i've added the store code. And how can i change it into an object rather than a string. State is a string by default isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are having a problem is because `SecureStore` only saves strings. You quite correctly used `JSON.stringify` to conert the object into a string so that you could save it, however you need to convert it back into a object.

You can use `JSON.parse` to convert your string back into an object.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state={
    UserData: {} // update this to an object
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync('userData')
    .then((data) => {
        let UserData = JSON.parse(data) // you need to parse the string to json
        console.log(UserData); // you probably want to check what you have gotten back 
        this.setState({ UserData: UserData }) // then save the object to state
    });
}
```

Now as long as your object has the keys `Firstname` and `Lastname` you should be able to access them like this

```
this.state.UserData.Firstname
this.state.UserData.Lastname
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you for clarifying, I have learned a lot about what objects are and how to use them now.